# How to print custom common field for all request in logrus golang without impacting performance

Tags: go, go-gin

I want to add a custom field like requestId in logs and it should be printed along with message while calling
log.Info(message) or log.Debug(messasge)

Answer (score 2):

You should warp it by yourself

```
func (logger *MyLogger) Debug(direction string, i *LogInfo, msg string) {
    logger.Log.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
        "method":     i.method,
        "path":       i.path,
        "direction":  direction,
        "clientIP":   i.clientIP,
        "userAgent":  i.userAgent,
        "dataLength": i.dataLength,
        "func":       i.function,
        "line":       i.line,
    }).Debug(msg)
}
```

and write a utily func can generate those paramter.

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve this using WithField or WithFields functions. If you want multiple fields use WithFields method.

Here is the function definition `func WithField(key string, value interface{}) *Entry`

An example: `log.WithField("requestId", "value").Info("Your log message here")`

For more information https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus

Comment: thanks for your reply, But i do not want in this way. I should add log.WithField("requestId", "value") at once place and it should reflect other place as well.

Comment: did you solve this issue? I'm looking for the same thing without having to call WithField every time